# VCS branch (mercurial & git) in vim statusline

Tags: git, vim, mercurial

I'm looking for how to display branch name (for both git and mercurial) in vim status line. Is there a plugin for that?

I was trying to use [vcprompt](https://github.com/djl/vcprompt)

```
function! GetVcpromptBranch()
    let result = system('vcprompt')
    return result
endfunction
```

and in .vimrc

```
set statusline= .... Branch\ %{GetVcpromptBranch()}
```

but this function is called very often, so everything slows. Is there some alternatives?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you don't mind referring to plugin, [powerline](https://github.com/Lokaltog/powerline) will be your friend :)

I'm using `powerline` only with `git`, but it seems also support `mercurial` from [here](http://choorucode.com/2013/02/17/how-to-install-and-use-vim-powerline-plugin-for-vim/).

Comment: Tnx, I completely forgot about powerline)

Answer (score 0):

The original [vcprompt](https://bitbucket.org/gward/vcprompt) was written in C, precisely to avoid the problem you described. It's fast and lightweight.